# How to make multiple inserts with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables to which I have to make insert to

**Table 1 : Project**

- projectId
- Name
- Description

**Table 2 : Access**

- id
- userId
- projectId

Now I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Entity Framework, now my question is how do I make insert to both this table ?

I mean I know I can make insert to Table 1 using EF, but then I need the projectId(which is generated with the first insert) to make the second insert.

I am not sure of how to go about it. Please some one guide me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save an object, the EF will populate the auto generated Key fields of the inserted objects:

```
public ActionResult Index() { 

    var ctx = new FooBarDbContext();

    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.Bar = "FooBar";
    ctx.Foos.Add(foo);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // now you have the Id for Foo object.

    var bar = new Bar();
    bar.FooId = foo.Id;
    ctx.Bars.Add(bar);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    // do what you need now.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

public ActionResult Index()

{

```
ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext ();
var project = new Project();
var access = new Access();

project.Name = “Project Name”;
project.Description = “Project Description”;

access.UserId = 1; // Fill with your userId
access.Project = project;

db.Access.Add(access);
db.SaveChanges();// save project and access
```

}

// In Models folder

public class ProjectContext: DbContext

{

```
 public DbSet<Project> User { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Access> Contact { get; set; }
```

}

// Also in Access Class you must define Project

public class Access

{

```
[Key]
public int id{ get; set; }
public int UserId {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("Project")]
public int ProjectId { get; set; }

public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
// This line make relation between project and access
```

}